# Show the hidden JFrame

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jframe

When I run my `JFrame` it shows me in hidden size. I have to resize to see JFrame.
Why I cannot get fully sized `JFrame`.
I used: `Pack(); setVisible(true);` but it doesn't work.
Here is my code:

```
public class Mytest extends JFrame{
      JLabel label=new JLabel();
      JLabel label2=new JLabel();
      Timer myTimer;
    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Mytest().show();

    }

    public Mytest(){
       getContentPane().setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
       setTitle("test");

       GridBagConstraints gridCon=new GridBagConstraints();
       gridCon.gridx=0;
       gridCon.gridy=0;
       getContentPane().add(label,gridCon);

       gridCon.gridx=0;
       gridCon.gridy=1;
       getContentPane().add(label2,gridCon);

       myTimer = new Timer(1000,new ActionListener(){
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
               myTimerActionPerformed(e);
           }
       });

        pack();
       myTimer.start();
       setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    }

    private void myTimerActionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    Date today=new Date();
    label.setText(DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(today));
    label2.setText(DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(today));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can maximize frame like this :

```
setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
```

or you can size frame as per your requirement like

```
setSize(500,500);
```

and you have to add below statement as i cant see this in your code

```
setVisible(true);
```

Comment: with setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); I got full screen JFrame, is it possible get like: setSize(500,500)?

Comment: @Dirak - yes definately you can size as per your requirement as you mentioned

Comment: Yes it worked with code:  setSize(500,500);
                          setVisible(true);

Comment: The problem is, pack should work. It possible that show is not doing something thing that setVisible is

Answer (score 3):

There are two basic problems...

The first is, when you create and add your `JLabel`s, they have no content, therefore their preferred size is `0x0`...

The second is the use of `pack`, from the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#pack())

> Causes this Window to be sized to fit the preferred size and layouts
>   of its subcomponents. The resulting width and height of the window are
>   automatically enlarged if either of dimensions is less than the
>   minimum size as specified by the previous call to the setMinimumSize
>   method.
>  If the window and/or its owner are not displayable
>   yet, both of them are made displayable before calculating the
>   preferred size. The Window is validated after its size is being
>   calculated.

So, basically, you are adding two labels, whose total combined size is `0x0` and `pack` is doing exactly what it was designed to, packing the frame to meet the requirements of the layout manager.

You need to seed the values of the labels before you call `pack`, for example, add a method that updates the labels, for example...

```
public void updateLabels() {
    Date today = new Date();
    label.setText(DateFormat.getDateInstance(DateFormat.FULL).format(today));
    label2.setText(DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(today));
}
```

Then in your constructor, before you call pack, call this method...

```
updateLabels();
pack();
myTimer.start();
setLocationRelativeTo(null);
```

(You should also call this `updateLabels` method from the `Timer`s `actionPerformed` method to keep it consistent).

This will seed the labels with some content, which `pack` and the layout manager can use to determine size of the window...

[image: Happy Window]

You should also use `setVisible` over `show` as `show` is deprecated and may be removed at some time in the future

Comment: Thank you very much for detailed answer, many things become more clear

Comment: 1+ Mad, question for you: do you have any public repository Swing programs that folks (such as me) can analyze and learn from? Thanks!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yeah, it's called  stack overflow ;)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels The other question is, what would be worth putting into it?

Comment: My concern is re my programming knowledge. I feel that I understand small Java GUI programs well but am still completely ignorant of the structure and connections of large real programs, and so am looking for examples of larger programs to study.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Oddly enough, the basic principles don't change.  Focus on re-use and decoupled code. Think to yourself how hard/easy would it be to pull out sections of the code and replace it with different implementations. MVC scales, that is, a MVC may contain other MVC's which make a the greater whole. Code to interfaces wherever possible. Avoid extending from top level containers and use a container manager/factory instead (so you could create a external and internal frame manager or a tabbed pane manager or what ever).

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Abstraction is important as it helps generate layers of re-usable code, sure at some point, your code will do a dedicated job, but adding, deleting and updating data from a database is pretty much the same process (or at least it should be unless you work for my company then it's different for every application we write <sigh>)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels If you're really unsure, you look into things like J2EE, basic MVC web apps and even things like iOS and Android for different takes on the same principles.

Comment: `"...use a container manager/factory instead (so you could create a external and internal frame manager or a tabbed pane manager or what ever)."` -- stuff like this is among the concepts I'm ignorant of. Well, I've bothered you enough with this. Thanks for taking the time to post this information. It is much appreciated!

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You learn this stuff when you want to change the way your program works (I stole that particular idea from NetBeans actually ;))